# litelement - building and bundling a webcomponent that includes assets

Tags: web-component, rollupjs, lit-element

I'm using litelement to build a web component. I started with the following repo to get started, which is a boilerplate for a project setup including rollup as a bundler.

https://github.com/PolymerLabs/lit-element-build-rollup

I'm able to build a component and use it. Now I want to build a component that will include an image. I'm not sure how to handle this. I don't want the consumers of the component to pass the image path as a property. The image should be bundled with the component.

`mycomponent.js`:

```
import {html, LitElement, css} from 'lit-element';
import logo from "./assets/mylogo.png";

class MyComponent extends LitElement {

    static get styles() {

        return [
            css`
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
            `,
        ];
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <div class="container">
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <img src={ {logo} } />
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
        `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

My VSCode editor says, I'm not using the `logo` that I imported in line 2. When I try to use the component after building it, the image does not appear and looks like it's looking for it in the wrong path.

I added the https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-image plugin and configured it in `rollup.config.js`, which looks like this:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import image from 'rollup-plugin-img';

export default ['MyComponent'].map((name, index) => ({

    input: `src/components/${name}.js`,
    output: {
        // file: 'build/index.js',
        format: 'iife',
        sourcemap: true,
        name,
        dir: 'build/public'
    },
    plugins: [
        postcss({
            extensions: ['.css'],
        }),
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        babel(),
        image({
            output: `build/public/assets`,
        })
  ]

}));
```

Does anyone has an example of bundling an asset (i.e. image) into a webcomponent?

Answer (score 1):

`rollup-plugin-image` loads the imported image file as base64 and provides an `HTMLImageElement` as default export with the content inlined in the `src` attribute (see [here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-image/blob/master/src/index.js#L26)).

Here you're interpolating the entire image element in the `src` (also, the template literal interpolation is wrong: should be `${}`, not `{{}}`).

```html
<img src={ {logo} } />
```

Try to interpolate the image itself instead:

```
${logo}
```

Also, the image plugin seems not to have an `output` setting:

```
// rollup.config.js

image({
  output: `build/public/assets`, <-- this has no effect
})
```

The accepted options are `include` and `exclude` (minimatch patterns or arrays of minimatch patterns of files to include or ignore). If you want to accept all image types just leave it empty:

```
image()
```

#### Image plugin issue

At this point everything should be fine except the `rollup -c` command failing with this error:

```
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by ./assets/mylogo.png
```

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-image/issues/2) of the plugin used with recent versions of rollup for which a PR was opened. Until they decide to merge it you can use the working fork:

```sh
$ npm uninstall rollup-plugin-image
$ npm i -D @timdp/rollup-plugin-image
```

```
// rollup.config.js
import image from 'rollup-plugin-image' --> '@timdp/rollup-plugin-image';
```

Comment: Thanks @Umbo for the details. You're right, I should be writing the image value as `${logo}`. I just realized that I mentioned the wrong rollup plugin in my description. I'm actually using `rollup-plugin-img` (https://github.com/alwaysonlinetxm/rollup-plugin-img). That's why my config had an `output` option.

Comment: Now my issue is bundling some demo html files. As you can see my rollup config is bundling my component (`src/components/<component-name>.js`) and the image. I also have some demo html files that I am copying to the `build` directory. In those html files my component does not render the image because it's looking for the image relative to where that demo file is, instead of relative to where the source of the component is. Do I need to process my demo html files using rollup too?

Comment: Are you serving the `build` directory correctly or just opening the html files from the file system?

Comment: Yes I am serving the build directory; not opening the html files directly.

Comment: Ok, and what is the exact error log that the browser gives for the failed request? Oh - just to be sure - you wrote "I should be writing the image value as `${logo}`" but if the plugin is `rollup-plugin-img` you were totally right, this is the correct thing to do: `<img src=${logo} />` (not just `${logo}`).

Comment: There's no error message actually. I see a usual icon that represent a broken image url. Looks like the image source is being set as `public/assets/mylogo.png`. So, the html file that is using that component has to be in a relative location so that it can access it. I just tried to use the component in a React component after installing the built files using `yarn install` and then imported the component as `import my-library/public/mycomponent.js`. Then I use the component as `<my-component></my-component>` but the image is not being rendered. I think I'm missing a key piece of the setup.

Comment: "So, the html file that is using that component has to be in a relative location so that it can access it" Of course, but aren't you copying the html files to the `build` directory?

Comment: Yes I am copying the html files to the `build` directory but I had them in a separate directory initially. But if the consumer has to be relative path, how would I use the components by doing `npm install` and then importing them into a react component? Does the consuming component have to perform aditional bundling?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution it to make a base64 encoded version of the PNG and place it into `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,.....">` of course you want the correct image mime type in there, but this way the image is embedded into the component.